# Does Qfield include SSL?

Tags: qgis, postgresql, qfield, ssl

I am a beginner in this field.

I am working with PostgreSQL, Qgis, and Q-field to collect data on the field.

As you know, I am searching for methods to keep security my database when I open a firewall to connect Qfield database on my phone to the PostgreSQL server.

If we connect the PostgreSQL database to Qgis has SSL, after that package Qgis project by Q-field plugin and send it to mobile. Is it work? Because I don't see any document talk about OpenSSL on mobile.

I see everyone prioritize choosing SSL. I also see other methods as password enhancement and configure settings with specific IP, but as you know, when I go to the field, I use 4g on my phone, this IP always changes every day.

So I want to know are there other methods to help security databases when opening a firewall to connect Q-field and PostgreSQL?

Comment: Qfield supports SSL https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/70 since QField 1.0 on Mar 26, 2018

Comment: @Mapperz It is perfect, thanks for your information.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to security, I suggest also considering the availability of your database when users are not connected to 3g/4g/5g network.

It is more secure and better practice to make your database available offline to your users. You can then run some processing tasks to consolidate the data to your Postgresql.

One way we have solved the issue for https://inputapp.io (a mobile app based on QGIS) is using DB-Sync:
https://github.com/lutraconsulting/mergin-db-sync

In summary: it creates a database file (GeoPackage) from your Postgresql and you can then use the GeoPackage file on your devices for offline data collection. When users are back online and sync the data, a daemon on the server syncs the Postgresql with the cloud storage.